# Test windows authentication in Local Machine

Tags: asp.net-membership

How could i test this windows authentication functionality in local machine as i dont have intranet,and systems under domain.

Comment: you may want to describe your problem as your questions doesn't point out what you really want to know

Answer (score 1):

to take a stab in the dark I'm assuming you have IIS running on your machine hosting a site that is configured to requires windows authentication?

I think the easiest option is to try and connect to the IIS machine from a second machine and see if you can login with the credentials you use on the server.  If you don't have a second machine then you could download VMWare Player and an Ubuntu Appliance (or grab Virtual-Box and build a VM of whatever you like) and use that to act as your second machine.